# Generic Class does not forward delegate calls to concrete subclass

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift3

Given the following.

```
protocol EntityType {
    var displayString: String { get }
}

extension String: EntityType {
    var displayString: String { return self }
}

class GenericListViewController<Entity>: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate where Entity: EntityType {
    let items: [Entity]

    let tableView: UITableView

    init(items: [Entity]) {
        self.items = items
        self.tableView = UITableView()

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        ])

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row].displayString

        return cell
    }

//    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        
//    }
}

class StringListViewController: GenericListViewController<String> {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected: \(items[indexPath.row])")
    }
}
```

Why isn't `tableView:didSelectRowAt:` being called in the concrete subclass? This works fine for non-generic types or when the parent class has an implementation and the sub-class overrides it. Is this expected behavior, Swift bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Still get this problem in Swift 4.1

Answer (score 2):

It does seem like a possible bug. My guess it that it might have something to do with the fact that Swift generics are not visible to the Objective-C runtime, so even though your methods implemented directly in `GenericListViewController<Entity>` are being called, there may be some buggy behavior between the Swift and Obj-C runtimes trying to figure out overrides. Definitely worth a bug report.

I will note though, that in strict OOP abstract superclasses generally do not conform to protocols themselves, they simply provide default implementations.  It's still up to the concrete subclasses to declare protocol conformance and fill in any missing implementations.

In the case of your code above, your `GenericListViewController<Entity>` class should not conform to `UITableViewDataSource` or `UITableViewDelegate`.  It simply provides the default method implementations that would allow a concrete subclass to conform without having to rewrite those method implementations (unless override is desired). Your `StringListViewController` should be the one declaring conformance to the two protocols. If you modify your code to do that, it will actually work as expected.

This doesn't change the fact that you have probably discovered a bug in Swift / Obj-C interop, though. I believe that what you have currently *should* work, although it's not the strict OOP way of handling protocol conformance.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I appreciate the feedback and I agree. I ultimately should rearchitect this thought, but now this behavior has me curious. It definitely seems inter-op related.

Comment: Hey, i wasted hours on the same problem today. Where can we report this?

Comment: I just opened a similar question around this. This is a good answer but it does present a problem. @DanielHall Consider using a concrete baseclass so that you can pass any subclass that inherits it as the concrete class. *or* you can pass the base class and cast it inside the generic (great for working with arrays of different types. kind of like type erasure). Will try removing base protocols.

My version of this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55945140/swift-subclasses-used-in-generics-dont-get-called-when-inheriting-from-nsobject

Also submitted a question to apple.

Comment: Just wanted to contribute some additional findings...I played around with my own sample delegate and wasn't able to recreate the issue until I made its method optional (requiring the @objc keyword) and only implemented it in the child/generic class.